# how to use real time index in sphinx with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, full-text-search, real-time, sphinx

OS: windows 2003
DB:MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2
Sphinx 2.0.4
Quesion:
  When database data changes,I can use SphinxQL statements update index in.NET?